# FTDI to basic C programming

Tags: c, ubuntu, ftdi

I'm currently programming an 8-channel usb relay on ubuntu 12.04 using C.
 I already created a simple program that will write to the port but the relay doesn't response.
This is the program I used to send command to the relay.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#include <errno.h>
#include <termios.h>

//serial
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>

int main()
{
    int con;
    char *portname = "/dev/ttyUSB0";

    con = open(portname, O_RDWR | O_NOCTTY | O_SYNC);
    if(con < 0) {
            printf("[ERROR] %d opening %s: %s", errno, portname, strerror (errno));
            return -1;
    }

    int speed;
    int baudrate = 9600;
    int parity   = 0;

    switch(baudrate)
    {
    case 0:
    case 9600:
        speed = B9600;
        break;
    case 1:
    case 19200:
        speed = B19200;
        break;
    case 2:
    case 38400:
        speed = B38400;
        break;
    case 3:
    case 57600:
        speed = B57600;
        break;
    case 4:
    case 115200:
        speed = B115200;
        break;
    default:
        printf("Baud rate out of range");
        return -1;
    }

    struct termios tty;
    memset (&tty, 0, sizeof tty);
    if (tcgetattr (con, &tty) != 0)
    {
            return -1;
    }

    cfsetospeed (&tty, speed);
    cfsetispeed (&tty, speed);

    tty.c_cflag = (tty.c_cflag & ~CSIZE) | CS8;     // 8-bit chars
    // disable IGNBRK for mismatched speed tests; otherwise receive break
    // as \000 chars

    tty.c_iflag &= ~IGNBRK;         // disable break processing
    tty.c_lflag = 0;                // no signaling chars, no echo,
                                    // no canonical processing
    tty.c_oflag = 0;                // no remapping, no delays

    tty.c_cc[VMIN]  = 100;                  // read doesn't block
    tty.c_cc[VTIME] = 5;                 // 0.5 seconds read timeout

    tty.c_iflag &= ~(IXON | IXOFF | IXANY); // shut off xon/xoff ctrl

    tty.c_cflag |= (CLOCAL | CREAD);        // ignore modem controls,
                                            // enable reading
    tty.c_cflag &= ~(PARENB | PARODD);      // shut off parity
    tty.c_cflag |= parity;
    tty.c_cflag &= ~CSTOPB;
    tty.c_cflag &= ~CRTSCTS;

    if (tcsetattr (con, TCSANOW, &tty) != 0)
    {
            printf("error %d from tcsetattr", errno);
            return -1;
    }

    unsigned char wbuf[1] = {0x01};

    int w = write(con, wbuf, 1);
    if(w < 0) {
        printf("error %d: %s", errno, strerror (errno));
        return -1;
    } else {
        printf("%d\n", w);
    }

    close(con);
    return 0;
}
```

The command I used in `write()` is to open the first relay light.
The return code of the `write()` is 1, but the relay has no response in the code which means the light didn't turn on.

My question is, is it possible to interact with the relay without using the ftdi libraries?

Comment: Is the code above successful? What is `con` and how did you `open` it? Did you ask FTDI? So please **edit your question** to improve it!

Comment: Ok sir, I'll edit it